# Flask and Flask-SocketIO integration and import errors

Tags: python, web, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to integrate Flask-SocketIO with my Flask application.

For some reason I am getting an import error that is triggered by the 
`from .. import socketio` that I have in my events.py and I am not sure why.

I would greatly appreciate any help provided.

app.py

```
from factory import create_app
app = create_app()
```

factory.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
import os
from celery import Celery

lm = LoginManager()
socketio = SocketIO()
lm.login_view = 'main.login'
lm.session_protection = 'strong'


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(os.environ.get('APP_CONFIG'))  # export APP_CONFIG=settings.Development
    lm.init_app(app)

    from project.main import main as main_blueprint

    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    socketio.init_app(app)

    return app
```

main/____init____.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
import views, events
```

main/events.py

```
# from __future__ import absolute_import
from uuid import uuid4
from flask import current_app, session, request
from flask.ext.socketio import emit, disconnect
from .. import socketio

@socketio.on('status', namespace='/events')
def events_message(message):
    print 'socketio.on: status'
    emit('status', {'status': message['status']})


@socketio.on('disconnect request', namespace='/events')
def disconnect_request():
    print 'socketio.on: disconnect request'
    emit('status', {'status': 'Disconnected!'})
    disconnect()


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/events')
def events_connect():
    print 'socketio.on: connect'
    websocket_id = str(uuid4())
    session['websocket_id'] = websocket_id
    current_app.clients[websocket_id] = request.namespace
    emit('websocket_id', {'websocket_id': websocket_id})
```

Comment: How to use it in production ? I mean `eventlet` server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `main/____init____.py` to `main/__init__.py` and you can do:

```
from . import socketio
```

if `socketio` is defined in `__init__.py` like you said. However, it looks like it's defined in `factory.py`, in which case you'd do:

```
from ..factory import socketio
```

Comment: Ok I must've typed one to many _ when I was entering the name of my init file on SO.